# I want to automatically input the myObj information to an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

What I want is that when making the request to the server it responds with a JSON and I want to save that in myObj so that I can enter it directly in the table in their respective fields.

I am not an expert and I do not know how to do many things, if I have some things wrong or many tell me and I will try to fix it. How should I do it? I've been trying and searching for a long time but I can't find anything.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>



    <body>

        <div id="contact">

            <h1>Invoice</h1>

        <form action="/table.html">
            <label for="invoice_id">Invoice:</label>
            <input type="text" id="invoice_id" name="invoice" placeholder="Enter Invoice Id" /><br>
            <button type="button"  id="form_button" value="Consultar">Consultar</button>

        </form>

    </div>

    <table id="demo">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Date</th>

                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Barcode</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody id="matchData"></tbody>
    </table>

    </body>

    <script>

    let button = document.getElementById("form_button");
    button.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let id = document.getElementById("invoice_id").value;

        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.addEventListener("load", function (e) {

            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                if (request.status == 200) {
                    console.log(request.responseText); // datos de la factura
                    // pasarla a objeto (JSON)
                    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);




                } else {
                    console.log("Error loading page\n");
                }
            }

        });
        request.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8081/invoice/" + 
    id);

        request.send();

    });

    </script>

    </html>
```

ANNOTATION:

Omg, thank you very much, you have helped me a lot, I almost have it.
It's true that I haven't put what my response looks like sorry, in JSON format it would look like this:

```
{"code":"Fact003","date":"2021-04-19T22:00:00.000Z","lines":[{"amount":2,"barcode":"6854952135","name":"Teclado Logitech","description":"Teclado Logitech Gaming","price":45},{"amount":5,"barcode":"9465986321","name":"Monitor HP 27f","description":"Monitor de 27\" HD","price":200},{"amount":3,"barcode":"5216854935","name":"Ratón Logitech","description":"Ratón Logitech Gaming","price":50}]}
```

Or this:

```
code    :   Fact003
date    :   2021-04-19T22:00:00.000Z
lines       [3]
0       
amount  :   2
barcode :   6854952135
name    :   Keyboard Logitech
description :   Keyboard Logitech Gaming
price   :   45
1       
amount  :   5
barcode :   9465986321
name    :   Monitor HP 27f
description :   Monitor de 27\" HD
price   :   200
2       
amount  :   3
barcode :   5216854935
name    :   Mouse Logitech
description :   Mouse Logitech Gaming
price   :   50
```

So when I do the var myObj = {....} it doesn't give me the latest data, I know why it is but I can't solve it, thanks in advance. I am trying to get the information in this way and the code and the date give it to me but the rest of the information does not.

```
                var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

                var myObj = {
                    code: data.code,
                    date: data.date,
                    lines: []

                };

                for (let i = 0; i < JSON.parse(request.responseText); i++) {
                    data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    let line = {
                        amount: data.amount,
                        barcode: data.barcode,
                        name: data.name,
                        description: data.description,
                        price: data.amount

                    };
                    myObj.lines[i] = line;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by iterating over `myObj` with a for-in-loop and creating cells with the values as `textContent`.

```js
let table = document.getElementById('matchData');
let row = document.createElement("tr");

for (var key in myObj) {
    let cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.textContent = myObj[key];
    row.appendChild(cell);
}

table.appendChild(row);
```

Since your response object has only one code- and date-value but multiple nested lines you need two additional, inner for loops. One for adding code and date (both with rowspan equals line count) together with the values of the first line to a first row, and a second for adding the remaining lines to further rows.

**Working example** without the ajax request but with hardcoded dummy data (no need to type the invoice id, just press the button):

```js
var myObj = {
  "code": "Fact003",
  "date": "2021-04-19T22:00:00.000Z",
  "lines": [{
    "amount": 2,
    "barcode": 6854952135,
    "name": "Keyboard Logitech",
    "description": "Keyboard Logitech Gaming",
    "price": 45
  }, {
    "amount": 5,
    "barcode": 9465986321,
    "name": "Monitor HP 27f",
    "description": "Monitor de 27\" HD",
    "price": 200
  }, {
    "amount": 3,
    "barcode": 5216854935,
    "name": "Mouse Logitech",
    "description": "Mouse Logitech Gaming",
    "price": 50
  }]
};
let button = document.getElementById("form_button");

button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  let table = document.getElementById('matchData');
  let line_count = myObj["lines"].length;
  let row = document.createElement("tr");

  for (let key in myObj) {

    if (key == "code" || key == "date") {
      let cell = document.createElement("td");

      cell.rowSpan = line_count;
      cell.textContent = myObj[key];
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }

    if (key == "lines") {
      for (let line_key in myObj[key][0]) {
        let cell = document.createElement("td");

        cell.textContent = myObj[key][0][line_key];
        row.appendChild(cell);
      }

      table.appendChild(row);

      for (let i = 1; i < line_count; i++) {
        let row = document.createElement("tr");

        for (let line_key in myObj[key][i]) {
          let cell = document.createElement("td");

          cell.textContent = myObj[key][i][line_key];
          row.appendChild(cell);
        }

        table.appendChild(row);
      }
    }
  }

});
```

```css
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact">
  <h1>Invoice</h1>

  <form action="/table.html">
    <label for="invoice_id">Invoice:</label>
    <input type="text" id="invoice_id" name="invoice" placeholder="Enter Invoice Id" /><br>
    <button type="button" id="form_button" value="Consultar">Consultar</button>
  </form>
</div>

<table id="demo">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Barcode</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="matchData"></tbody>
</table>
```

By the way: Since your button is `type="button"` you don't need `e.preventDefault()` (it would only be necessary for `type="submit"`)...

Comment: Thanks, I have already corrected what you have told me and it works halfway for me because another problem has appeared.